# High speed data interface for upto 5 meter

Tags: communication, digital-communications

I have to interface two processor boards sitting at a distance of about 5 meters away. The data transfer rate is about 128 MBps (Mega Bytes per seconds) or 1 Gbps(giga bits per seconds).

Which interface can achieve such high data rate full duplex communication?

Thanks

Comment: Is it net throughput requirement? What about latency? What kind of data is tranferred? What about lost data? Should resend? ANything else, like cost, design effort?

Comment: See [Comparing Bus Solutions](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slla067).

Comment: Cables make pretty good high-speed data interfaces.

Comment: @Andyaka, you and your radical theories! :P

Comment: What about USB?

Comment: @user3528438 - Don't get fooled by clock rates. USB 2.0, with a nominal clock rate of 480 Mb/s only has a maximum effective rate on the order of 50 Mb/s, due to packet and protocol details. See https://superuser.com/questions/317217/whats-the-maximum-typical-speed-possible-with-a-usb2-0-drive.  So USB 3 is probably adequate. Of course, USB doesn't do full duplex, so it's not really suited to the OP request.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Don't mix up MBits and MBytes. At 480 MBits/second, 50 MBytes/second is not bad at all.

Comment: @JimmyB - Lower-case b in Mb/s specifies bits, not bytes.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 50MBits (6MB!) is way too low for USB 2. 20MB/s are easily achievable, 30 maybe, when transfering data e.g. to/from an external HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your budget really.
A very good choice will be fiber optical cable. It supports both simplex and duplex modes. 
You can also use use a coaxial cable. they are available in various grades with different terminations, so you need to choose your cable carefully.

Answer (score 0):

An 1 Gbps Ethernet link would do the job in this case. Might be a bit too much effort, though, both from the hardware and the software side. But it certainly offers the speed you are looking for, the full-duplex requirement and the 5m are way below Ethernet's max distance.

Comment: Ethernet probably means UDP/IP or something like that, eventually up to 40% data overhead and unclear latency.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum You don't **have** to use anything above MAC layer.

Comment: Do you know many application that don't use anything? I know just one.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Some proprietary camera interfaces.

Comment: One i know is also proprietary. So this is like Andy Aka said: Cables make pretty good high-speed data interfaces

Comment: @GregoryKornblum But why do you say 40% data overhead. If big frames are used, and not the min of 64 bytes, the data overhead is much better, no? But for sure, for latency critical application the Ethernet link will not be a good option at all.

Comment: Agreed for latency critical apps. Overhead- i said up to 40%. Although even for camera application i was involved in this is a realistic figure. When you have for example a switch involved in the network, you become dependent on other things, not just frame size.